# How to install flash player in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

I am new to both Ubuntu and Linux operating sytem. I have no idea how to do common things, I want to know how to install flash player from adobe in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS because I added a game and it asks to install flash player.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this is what you are refering to:
     `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Way to go

1. Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
2. Type that code piece of code.

(You might need to restart both system or browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on browser.

Best alternative is to install chromium browser. It includes a built in flash player, no separate client is needed. It replaces the protocol, not just another copy of same browser addon/library.

If you insist on Firefox, there is flashplugin-installer package you can get in multiverse repository. It downloads from Adobe. It puts an 'so' file is a place where FF finds it.

Don't get your hopes up. I've got it in firefox, but it crashes constantly. The problem to remember is Adobe dropped the Linux Firefox add on project years ago. Nobody is trying very hard to make it go. I spent most of weekend testing and trying to fix. It can connect to start session, always fails as soon as you click something (Firefox 55). I can confirm that chromium is good alternative. Interesting, for me, that I don't enjoy chromium, but it is only flash alternative in Linux.